# Returning html tags in Django

Tags: django

I have a view function, which is returning a HTML page:

```
render_to_response("test.html", {test: value, somehtml: '<h1>t<h1>'})
```

Now, the `somehtml` value is rendered as a string and not as HTML with tags. How can I return HTML tags in my template?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, got the answer: using the `safe` filter.

```
{{ somehtml|safe }}
```

Comment: Please keep in mind that this is covered in detail in the documentation for Django's template system; looking at the docs is generally the best possible thing you can do when you don't yet know Django well enough to understand why something works a particular way.